# The method to set the HTTP headers in chrome browser with python selenium module?

Tags: python, selenium, http-headers, selenium-chromedriver

I know the way to change the user-agents with chrome driver in selenium. But I don't know how to set other fields of HTTP-headers(ex.accept, accept-languag, connection, upgrade-insecure-requests and so on).

Is there a way to change headers?
I use python version 3.6 and selenium module version 3.4.1.

Comment: Can't You use some of extensions for chrome. Like modifyHeaders or plugin like that?